# Create a variable number of objects and display all objects in java

Tags: java

I have a payroll program here and I want to be able to add objects to the Employee class. Currently I define the object emp that relates to the Employee class. What if I wanted to be able to dynamically create objects until I entered the STOP command in my script. Also, once I am done how could I print all objects related to the Employee class. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class PayrollProgram
{


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

    while (!emp.name.equals("STOP"))
    {
    Employee emp = new Employee();

    System.out.print("Employee's Name: ");
    emp.name = scan.next();

    if(emp.name.equals("STOP"))
        {
            System.out.printf("The Application is STOPPING......");
        break;
        }

    System.out.print("Enter hourly wage: $ ");
    emp.wage = scan.nextDouble();
    while (emp.wage < 0) 
    {
        System.out.printf("Please Enter a Positive Number! \n");
        System.out.print("Enter hourly wage: $ ");  
        emp.wage = scan.nextDouble();
    }

    System.out.print("Hours Worked in Week: ");
    emp.hours = scan.nextDouble();
    while (emp.hours < 0) 
    {
        System.out.printf("Please Enter a Positive Number! \n");
        System.out.print("Hours Worked in Week: ");
        emp.hours = scan.nextDouble();
    }

    employees.add(emp);
    emp.printEmployee();

    }
    for(Employee emp : employees)
        {
        System.outprintln(emp.name);
        }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a datastructure (typically a list in this case) that holds every employee. Each loop you just create a new employee and add it to the list. Afterwards you can print everything.

```
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

while (!emp.name.equals("STOP")) {
 Employee emp = new Employee();
 // read all the data from input

 employees.add(emp);
}

for(Employee emp : employees) {
 System.out.println(emp.name);
}
```

Comment: I am receiving a "cannot find symbol" error when I run. Do I have to declare the list?

Comment: edit your post with the code, I can't tell without seeing it.

Comment: "System.outprintln(emp.name);" You forgot a "." between "out" and "println".